# 14.04 updates broke Java

Tags: 14.04, updates, java, netbeans

Yesterday (8/15/2018) the regular Ubuntu updates on 14.04 LTS caused Java to stop working on two different VirtualBox machines.  Netbeans 8.2, reliable until now, can no longer start up, and after a delay I get a kernel oops in the java process.

After this happened to my first machine, I made a duplicate copy of my hard drive image (.vdi) before allowing the update on the second machine.  After the update (which required a reboot), Netbeans was broken on this machine like the other.  After I restored the .vdi this morning (and declined the update!) Netbeans is functional again.

Is anyone else having this sort of problem?  Thanks!

Comment: 14.04 LTS is supported into April 2019, according to https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life and also this web site's [14.04] tag.  Anyway, I'm stuck with the version of Ubuntu that supports the build tools I need for my job.

Comment: It is, indeed, still supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that kernel 3.13.0-155 broke things. We also ran into this and had to revert back to 3.13.0-153. It doesn't seem to be just related to Java; we had our AWS EC2 instance completely fail to reboot with the new Kernel.

Canonical is aware of this issue and [their kernel team is working to fix it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1787127).

UPDATE: Canonical has [fixed](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3741-3/) this issue in 3.13.0-156 kernel.

Comment: The Ubuntu update on 8/20 included kernel 3.13.0-156 which solved the Java problem.  Meanwhile, thank you Kaitsu for pointing me at the bug report, and also telling me what I could do to work around it before the fix.